# Redux Middleware, POST Request

Tags: api, dart, redux, middleware

I wrote functions for sending requests using `redux api middleware`. What does the POST function look like instead of GET?

```
RSAA getOrdersRequest(){
  return RSAA(
    method: 'GET',
    endpoint: 'http://10.0.2.2:80/order',
    types: [
      LIST_ORDERS_REQUEST,
      LIST_ORDERS_SUCCESS,
      LIST_ORDERS_FAILURE,
    ],
    headers: {
      'Content-Type':'application/json',
    },
  );
}

ThunkAction<AppState> getOrders() => (Store<AppState> store) => store.dispatch(getOrdersRequest());
```

my function is written in dart, but the language of the example is not important,

thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For making async calls, you should use middlewares like `redux-thunk`. I'll be using JavaScript here.

All you need to know about thunk is that `redux-thunk` allows your action creator(like `postOrder`) to return a function which then dispatches respective actions(object with a `type` and `payload/data` property) to the store. You can dispatch as many actions as you like.

`POST` is just a `HTTP` verb that I'm using to post an order, as you could see down here. Firstly, `POST_ORDERS_REQUEST` is the beginning of your request, in which, you could show loading... state or a spinner in your application. So, this action fires off, `orderReducer` checks what `type` of action has arrived, and in turn, acts accordinly and stores the data in the redux-store. I'm sure you know basic redux, so it might not be a problem for you to understand all this. The other two actions work the same way.

```js
export const postOrder = () => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: POST_ORDER_REQUEST
    })
    try {
      const res = await axios.post("http://10.0.2.2:80/order",
        {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          }
        })
      dispatch({
        type: POST_ORDER_SUCCESS,
        data: { order: res.data.order }
      })
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({
        type: POST_ORDER_FAILURE,
        data: { error: `Order failed with an ${err}` }
      })
    }
  }
}
```

You could accordingly create your `orderReducer`, for example:

```js
const initialState = {
  isLoading: false,
  myOrder: null,
  error: null
}

export const orderReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case POST_ORDER_REQUEST:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: true,
        error: null
      }
    case POST_ORDER_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        myOrder: action.data.order,
        error: null
      }
    case POST_ORDER_FAILURE:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        error: action.error
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

You can read these good articles on Redux that you might like:

https://daveceddia.com/what-is-a-thunk/

https://daveceddia.com/where-fetch-data-redux/

Answer (score 1):

since accepted response had nothing to do with [`redux api middleware`](https://github.com/agraboso/redux-api-middleware) which is made in order to reduce "boilerplatish" and repetitive thunk code, you can use `createAction` from `redux-api-middleware` like:

```js
import { createAction } from "redux-api-middleware";

export const getOrders = () =>
  createAction({
    endpoint: 'http://10.0.2.2:80/orders',
    method: "GET",
    types: ['GET_ORDERS_PENDING', 'GET_ORDERS_SUCCESS', 'GET_ORDERS_FALED'],
  });

export const getOrderById = (id) =>
  createAction({
    endpoint: `http://10.0.2.2:80/orders/${id}`,
    method: "GET",
    types: ['GET_ORDER_BY_ID_PENDING', 'GET_ORDER_BY_ID_SUCCESS', 'GET_ORDER_BY_ID_FALED'],
  });

export const submitOrder = (name, price) =>
  createAction({
    endpoint: 'http://10.0.2.2:80/orders',
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      name: name,
      price: price,
    }),
    types: ['SUBMIT_ORDER_PENDING', 'SUBMIT_ORDER_SUCCSESS', 'SUBMIT_ORDER_FAILED'],
  });
```

in cases where you could use more handling than simple api service calling you can always combine it with thunk like [this](https://github.com/agraboso/redux-api-middleware#dispatching-thunks)